# How do I know where to cut the fork tube?

Tags: fork

I am building a road bike and I am not sure where to cut the tube of my new fork. Is there a "standard" for how many spacers (or cm)?

[image]

Comment: There is no standard. If you don’t know based on past experience with other bikes, you should see a professional bike fitter to determine a good handlebar height for your body, riding style, and goals.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As others have mentioned, there's no standard. Basically, you figure out how many spacers you need and cut just below where the top of the spacer/stem stack. [You need a small gap](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/14175/is-it-safe-to-use-a-spacer-that-reaches-above-the-steerer-tube/14177#14177) so that the top cap can compress everything together.

The way I usually go about it is to fit everything together except for the top cap and tighten down the pinch bolts on the stem. Hop on the bike and *carefully* ride around in the driveway to see if it feels like it's the right height.

If you can't get a good feel for the height, add a couple of extra spacers. Over time, you can move them above the stem (which lowers the stem) one at a time until you get the right height. You could leave those extra spacers in place permanently. If you'd like to remove them, you'll have to cut the stem again. They don't hurt anything, they just look a little wonky.

Comment: If it's a nice bike that I intend to cherish for a long time, wouldn't it make sense to hedge my bets against a different sentiment in the future by cutting 5-10 mm higher than what I today consider optimal? (This of course assumes that the fork matches the frame in the first place.)

Comment: @Sam: 10mm of spacers on top of the stem is quite a usual sight and IMHO doesn’t look too horrible and probably won’t have much of an impact on aerodynamics, weight or crash risk/behavior. So yes, I’d also leave it a bit longer and keep 10mm of spacers on top.

Comment: @Michael Perfect. Thanks. We're so used to inspecting carefully just the bikes of racers rather than normal cyclists, that it's also nice to stress the differences.

Comment: @Sam Yup, cutting it a bit long and using extra spacers on top is perfectly fine. That's what I was trying to get at in the last paragraph. I probably could've worded it better. :/

Comment: @Sam Also, some fork and stem manufacturers recommend that you have a 5mm spacer on top, ensuring that the steerer goes all the way through the stem for safety reasons. It is my personal policy to always leave a 5mm safety spacer when trimming steerers.

Answer (score 6):

Nobody here can help with exact measurements. If you have an existing bike (or had a bikefit), you can measure reach and drop and try to get somewhere along these lines before cutting the steerer. When in doubt, better consult your LBS or a bikefitter.

It's no shame to keep a spacer or two on top to give you some room for future adjustment, i.e. when the position is too aggressive or if you fit a new stem. So, don't cut it flush with your actual position right away, you can still do that if you have a few miles in on your setup and you are fully confident with your position.

Answer (score 2):

This is inspired by juhist's answer. Also, it isn't 100% clear if you are asking about spacers below or above the stem.

In part, you should think about your riding goals. Those influence how many spacers you want below the stem. You can experiment with this by sitting on the bike with the steerer uncut, and just testing out. It is better if you can borrow someone's trainer, and you could try pedaling at a moderate pace. Otherwise, leaning against the wall will have to do.

You might want a very racey position, and you could aim for a torso angle (to the horizontal) of 30 degrees or less when in the hoods. The handlebars will be about 2 inches or more below the saddle. This position requires flexibility, although I've known even older athletes who are still functional enough to use a position like this.

Nobody is obliged to use a racey position. Many riders are better served by a torso angle from about 40 to 60 degrees. On drop bar bikes, it's typical for handlebars to be lower than your saddle. However, I believe that if that is what you need, handlebars level or even a bit above the saddle can still work.

If you want to ride in a position with the handlebars much above the saddle, then a drop bar bike may not work. You won't be able to get a neutral wrist angle when grasping the controls. Flat bar bikes and their controls will probably be better.

Traditionally, many people leave a few spacers above the stem in case they want to adjust their position. You actually can't have too many spacers above the stem, because your fork compression plug needs to support the steerer from inside around where the stem clamps the steerer. Other than that, it can certainly help with resale value, because replacement forks are expensive. That said, if you are certain about your position and you are certain about keeping the bike for the long term, then nobody should stop you from cutting the steerer to zero spacers above the stem.

Stem length and angle are also part of the fitting process. You will probably need to experiment with the stem length a bit. I think that a lot of stems are -10 degrees, rather than -17. Do note that you can flip a stem, i.e. a -10 will become +10, which will bring the bars higher and towards you (i.e. increase stack, decrease reach). This is something that you have to do in person when considering your riding goals. It is pretty common to change your riding position when you're newer to the sport.

At some point, you may want to seek out a bike fitter. It may be better to do this when you have a better idea about your goals. These services can be expenses, and many riders benefit from repeated fits over the years as their bodies and perhaps their goals change. It is still worth it for a lot of people, and you should definitely see a fitter if you have persistent pain when riding.

Answer (score 0):

**You can always substitute a collar for the threadless stem and use a quill stem.**

Why?   Because with a quill stem, you must choose the reach - which doesn't vary that much, but then have height adjustability with the length of the quill. With a cut threadless fork you must buy a stem that matches both reach and rise. Or leave a big ugly stub sticking up. A threaded headset provides clamping and pre-tension at the same time with a locknut and keyed washer. Threadless requires a star nut for the pre-tension, essentially a tool attached to your steering tube, but, hey, the makers don't have to cut threads.

One of the most obnoxious changes manufacturers have foisted on us.

Comment: It would still be quite tall!

Comment: I think this is talking about a threadless to quill adapter. The steerer is carbon. I have a feeling that the adapter won't work, since the expanding nut would bite into the carbon and cause a fracture.

Comment: Good point, I missed that.

Answer (score -7):

> I am building a road bike and I am not sure where to cut the tube of my new fork

Don't.

Cutting the fork steerer tube is is something that can't be undone later. It will reduce the resale value of your bike. It will make it impossible to do large adjustments to handlebar height without buying a new high-rise stem.

If you really have way too long steerer tube (I'm 99% certain you don't), here's one plan: pick a 17-degree stem. Set it on the fork so that it's facing down, so that the stem is perfectly horizontal (the 73-degree angle of the head tube cancels the 17-degree angle of the stem, creating a very aesthetically pleasant look with a perfectly horizontal stem). Then set the spacers such that the handlebars is at the highest level a person who might consider buying this bike might want to have. Usually that person is bit taller than you, so you set the handlebars to slightly higher than your saddle currently is, because it's entirely possible a buyer prefers handlebar at the same level as the saddle, and uses a bit higher saddle than you use.

Now, do you have any spacers above the stem? I bet you don't. But if you do, then you may consider cutting the steerer tube to reduce the spacer count above the stem to zero.

Comment: My bike will look like an unicorn if I don't cut it

Comment: @juhist The picture shows an Eifel Tower on top of his bike, so he will have to cut it for obvious reasons.

Comment: Well the picture wasn't there when I answered. I never cut my steerer tubes, but then again I have my handlebars up high.

Comment: One of the most obnoxious new requirements the manufacturers have foisted on us.  Fortunately you can still use a quill stem if you lock the headset down with an external clamp.

Comment: That steerer could do the rider some serious damage in an accident.  It should be trimmed for safety.

Comment: @juhist i added the pic after your answer to highlight the situation. Thanks!

Comment: @DoNuT What do you have against the French?!?

Comment: @MaplePanda Even the UCI wouldn't approve of such looks. 